# Sorting an array of objects based on a string value's index in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to sort a dataset by the string `rank` based on their location in an array. I tried using indexOf with sort to limited success. I did find another post similar, although it is not relating to my question for any quick duplicate reporters.

Dataset:

```
[
    {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b535f6eddfad00564b103db"
    },
    "notes": [
        "Very attractive"
    ],
    "warns": [],
    "username": "Saddy",
    "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/3c/3ce7fd0c1a5225790d67d90d4f1e60d2d29d2037_full.jpg",
    "id": "76561198151478478",
    "dateHired": {
        "$date": "2018-07-21T16:29:34.563Z"
    },
    "profile": "https://steamcommunity.com/id/dpitt/",
    "enactedBans": 0,
    "currentTickets": 0,
    "totalTickets": 0,
    "rank": "Administrator",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b54d085ed4855275f4cea63"
    },
    "notes": [],
    "warns": [],
    "username": "meme master nick",
    "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/f6/f61f5d62b79b22c9183c049521a4c587ab9334cd_full.jpg",
    "id": "76561198353773365",
    "dateHired": {
        "$date": "2018-07-22T18:44:21.814Z"
    },
    "profile": "https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198353773365/",
    "enactedBans": 0,
    "currentTickets": 0,
    "totalTickets": 0,
    "rank": "Owner",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b567169e7179a32d9cc2abe"
    },
    "notes": [],
    "warns": [],
    "username": "DarkGamer2k16",
    "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/3d/3dd1f81fc4556ae984ebe2312e1b9fc4ba54b5ea_full.jpg",
    "id": "76561194018842253",
    "dateHired": {
        "$date": "2018-07-21T16:29:34.563Z"
    },
    "profile": "https://steamcommunity.com/id/DarkGamer2k16/",
    "enactedBans": 0,
    "currentTickets": 0,
    "totalTickets": 0,
    "rank": "Moderator",
    "__v": 0
}
]
```

Failed Attempts:

```
console.log(arr.sort(function(a){ 
    return ["Owner", "Administrator", "Moderator"].indexOf(a.rank)
}))


arr.sort(function(a,b){ 
let sort = Object.assign({}, a, b);
    return["Owner", "Administrator", "Moderator"].indexOf(sort.rank)
})
```

both of the above are just replacing all data with mine. Thank you for your assistance

Expected Output:

```
[
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b54d085ed4855275f4cea63"
    },
    "notes": [],
    "warns": [],
    "username": "meme master nick",
    "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/f6/f61f5d62b79b22c9183c049521a4c587ab9334cd_full.jpg",
    "id": "76561198353773365",
    "dateHired": {
        "$date": "2018-07-22T18:44:21.814Z"
    },
    "profile": "https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198353773365/",
    "enactedBans": 0,
    "currentTickets": 0,
    "totalTickets": 0,
    "rank": "Owner",
    "__v": 0
},
    {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b535f6eddfad00564b103db"
    },
    "notes": [
        "Very attractive"
    ],
    "warns": [],
    "username": "Saddy",
    "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/3c/3ce7fd0c1a5225790d67d90d4f1e60d2d29d2037_full.jpg",
    "id": "76561198151478478",
    "dateHired": {
        "$date": "2018-07-21T16:29:34.563Z"
    },
    "profile": "https://steamcommunity.com/id/dpitt/",
    "enactedBans": 0,
    "currentTickets": 0,
    "totalTickets": 0,
    "rank": "Administrator",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b567169e7179a32d9cc2abe"
    },
    "notes": [],
    "warns": [],
    "username": "DarkGamer2k16",
    "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/3d/3dd1f81fc4556ae984ebe2312e1b9fc4ba54b5ea_full.jpg",
    "id": "76561194018842253",
    "dateHired": {
        "$date": "2018-07-21T16:29:34.563Z"
    },
    "profile": "https://steamcommunity.com/id/DarkGamer2k16/",
    "enactedBans": 0,
    "currentTickets": 0,
    "totalTickets": 0,
    "rank": "Moderator",
    "__v": 0
}
]
```

Comment: What's the expected output look like?

Comment: I'll update it in the post, one second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use both `a` and `b` in the arguments provided to `sort` - compare by the difference of their indicies in the `["Owner", "Administrator", "Moderator"]` array.

```js
const input=[{"_id":{"$oid":"5b535f6eddfad00564b103db"},"notes":["Very attractive"],"warns":[],"username":"Saddy","avatar":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/3c/3ce7fd0c1a5225790d67d90d4f1e60d2d29d2037_full.jpg","id":"76561198151478478","dateHired":{"$date":"2018-07-21T16:29:34.563Z"},"profile":"https://steamcommunity.com/id/dpitt/","enactedBans":0,"currentTickets":0,"totalTickets":0,"rank":"Administrator","__v":0},{"_id":{"$oid":"5b54d085ed4855275f4cea63"},"notes":[],"warns":[],"username":"meme master nick","avatar":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/f6/f61f5d62b79b22c9183c049521a4c587ab9334cd_full.jpg","id":"76561198353773365","dateHired":{"$date":"2018-07-22T18:44:21.814Z"},"profile":"https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198353773365/","enactedBans":0,"currentTickets":0,"totalTickets":0,"rank":"Owner","__v":0},{"_id":{"$oid":"5b567169e7179a32d9cc2abe"},"notes":[],"warns":[],"username":"DarkGamer2k16","avatar":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/3d/3dd1f81fc4556ae984ebe2312e1b9fc4ba54b5ea_full.jpg","id":"76561194018842253","dateHired":{"$date":"2018-07-21T16:29:34.563Z"},"profile":"https://steamcommunity.com/id/DarkGamer2k16/","enactedBans":0,"currentTickets":0,"totalTickets":0,"rank":"Moderator","__v":0}]

const ranks = ["Owner", "Administrator", "Moderator"];
input.sort((a, b) => ranks.indexOf(a.rank) - ranks.indexOf(b.rank));
console.log(input);
```

Comment: Thank you! I have been stuck on it for a while now. Once I can I will mark your as correct.